# Dibujar histogramas con R paquete ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Deseo dibujar un histograma y que sobre cada barra figure un número que indique la frecuencia exacta ya que éstos, por lo general, no coinciden con los valores que aparecen en el eje de ordenadas.Lo que hice, después de instalar paquete, es:

```
ggplot(datosN,aes(x=Aprobadas)) + 
      geom_histogram(fill="dodgerblue3",color="black",binwidth = 1) + 
      labs(title="Cantidad de Materias Aprobadas, 2015 - 2017",y="Cantidad")
```

¿Qué debería agregar para que se muestren los valores que deseo?

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una muestra de `datosN`?  la forma más sencilla es pegar la salida de este comando: `dput(head(datosN))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que estas buscando es esto:

```
df <- data.frame(foo=sample(1:10,200,replace=T))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(foo)))

g + geom_bar() +stat_count(aes(y=..count..,label=..count..),geom="text",vjust=-1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias!, es lo que buscaba.